# \r\n encoding issue when reading from DB & Java

Tags: java, database, encoding

I have a Java program that stores a message like "test1\r\ntest2" into DB - when I print this out it gives me new line.
The other thread is reading strings from DB and sending them to output with "\r\n"  and when I try to print this out it doesn't give me newline - it just prints out  "test1\r\ntest2"
Should I change the encoding of the output?

The application is deployed on tomcat with UTF-8 encoding set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some code snippets, in case it's two different calls translating differently. If it's different on input, maybe it's double-encoding them at some point and only singly-decoding.

Comment: sending is just passing arguments to SQL

// reading msg: String s_Messages = resultUnfinishedJobs.getColumnValueTrim(logWarn(), "MESSAGERESPONSE", i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the strings actually stored in the database as "\r\n"?

In that case I think you have to do a

```
String correct = dbString.replace("\\r\\n","\r\n")
```

on the strings returned from the database.

Comment: Yes they are actually stored as \r\n
I'm going to try right away :) Thanks!